# Python 3 ctypes call to a function that needs an indirect reference to a buffer through another structure

Tags: python, python-3.x, ctypes

I have a C shared library with a function that takes one argument.
This argument is a pointer to a structure with two fields.

```
    typedef struct
    {   
        uint8_t     *p_data; // Pointer to a fixed lenth buffer (100 bytes)
        uint16_t     len;    // number of valid bytes in the buffer (range 1-100)
    } data_t;
```

I need to setup a buffer of 100 bytes in my Python 3 script (I am using 3.7.2 / 3.7.3), 
load the library and call this function.

```
    int 
    fn_convert_buffer(data_t *data_p)
    {
        ...
    }
```

My Python 3 ctypes call attempt hits incompatible types.

```
    import ctypes as ct
    # load the library, etc...
    # lib_cdll = ct.CDLL(mySharedLib)

    def c_py_fn_convert_buffer(b_p):
            global lib_cdll
            val = lib_cdll.fn_convert_buffer(ct.byref(b_p))
            return int(val)

    data_a = bytearray(100)
    # Initialize the buffer with data.

    uint8_p = ct.c_uint8 * len(data_a)
    class BufferStruct_t (ct.Structure):
            _pack_ = 1
            _fields_ = [
                    ("p_data", ct.POINTER(ct.c_uint8 * len(data_a))),
                    ("len",    ct.c_uint16)
                    ]

    data_buf = BufferStruct_t(uint8_p.from_buffer(data_a), ct.c_uint16(8))
    # TypeError: incompatible types, c_ubyte_Array_100 instance 
    #            instead of LP_c_ubyte_Array_100 instance

    # Call C function in shared-library: int fn_convert_buffer(data_t *data_p);
    z = c_py_fn_convert_buffer(data_buf)
```

I need help in understanding what I've missed in the `BufferStruct_t` definition above. The `from_buffer` is supposed to get a pointer to the buffer but it seems to get `c_ubyte_ARRAY_100`.

A `byref()` on that does not work either

```
    data_buf = BufferStruct_t(ct.byref(uint8_p.from_buffer(data_a)), ct.c_uint16(8))
    # TypeError: expected LP_c_ubyte_Array_100 instance, got CArgObject
```

To test the basics of my flow, I made a sample case that will send the buffer and length parameters individually.

```
    def c_py_fn_convert_data(d_p,l):
            global lib_cdll
            val = lib_cdll.fn_convert_data(ct.byref(d_p),ct.c_uint32(l))
            return int(val)

    test_a = ct.c_uint8 * len(data_a)
    # Call C function in shared-library: 
    #   int fn_convert_data(uint8_t *data_p, uint32_t length); 
    z = c_py_fn_convert_data(test_a.from_buffer(data_a), 8)
```

This simplified case works.

How do I get about building a Python 3 object that carries a reference to a buffer that the shared-library function expects?

---

**Update with two variations that worked.**
**Update 1** Tried a `cast` based on something I read later (I don't cast lightly `:-)`)
Changed,

```
    data_buf = BufferStruct_t(uint8_p.from_buffer(data_a), ct.c_uint16(8))
```

to a pointer that is cast to refer an Array of specific length,

```
    data_buf = BufferStruct_t(cast(uint8_p.from_buffer(data_a),
                                   ct.POINTER(ct.c_uint8 * len(data_a))),
                              ct.c_uint16(8))
```

---

**Update 2** based on Mark's answer.
Changed `_field_` from,

```
                    ("p_data", ct.POINTER(ct.c_uint8 * len(data_a))),
```

to a simple-pointer form,

```
                    ("p_data", ct.POINTER(ct.c_uint8)),
```

---

Both variations worked.
**I am however curious to know which of these two ways is more safe/correct ctypes handling.**

1. Is it better to cast to the Array form? or,
2. Is it better to use simple pointers and rely on the length sent independently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your structure definition declared a pointer to an array, not a simple pointer as in the C structure.  Here's a working example with a simple implementation of the DLL where the function sums the data:

**test.c**

```
#include <stdint.h>

#ifdef _WIN32
#   define API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#   define API
#endif

typedef struct {
    uint8_t     *p_data;
    uint16_t     len;
} data_t;

API int fn_convert_buffer(data_t *data_p)
{
    int i;
    int sum = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < data_p->len; ++i)
        sum += data_p->p_data[i];
    return sum;
}
```

**test.py**

```
import ctypes as ct

class BufferStruct_t(ct.Structure):

    _pack_ = 1
    _fields_ = [("p_data", ct.POINTER(ct.c_uint8)), # just a pointer                    
                ("len",    ct.c_uint16)]

    # Helper to initialize the data
    def __init__(self,data):
        self.p_data = (ct.c_uint8 * len(data))(*data)
        self.len = len(data)

dll = ct.CDLL('test')
dll.fn_convert_buffer.argtypes = ct.POINTER(BufferStruct_t),
dll.fn_convert_buffer.restype = ct.c_int

data_buf = BufferStruct_t([1,2,3,4,5])
print(dll.fn_convert_buffer(data_buf))
```

Output:

```
15
```

Comment: I see your point. Will try the simple-pointer way with my code.

Comment: I am accepting your answer since is works for me. Have updated my question with one more way that worked for me (using a cast). Am curious to know which is the more safe/correct method for `ctypes`.

Comment: @nik The cast works, but the type being wrapped is `uint8_t*` so my method is correct.  You're basically casting it because the type is wrong.  What you had represents the C type `uint8_t(*)[100]` which isn't how it is declared.  If you have the correct type declared, you don't need the cast (which is exactly why you shouldn't cast lightly...it's usually a warning something is wrong :^)